Unit sphere separable in a separable normed space.
Let $(X, ||\cdot||)$ be a normed space and we suppose that the dual $X^*$ of $X$ is separable, then exists $\tilde{D}=(\tilde{f_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq X^*$ dense and countable. Now, we consider the unit sphere $$U=\{f\in X^*\;|\; ||f||_*=1\}.$$ I must prove that also $U$ is separable.
My attempt. We can suppose that $\tilde{f_n}\ne 0$ for all $n$ (Can this assumption be made?) and we consider the set $$D=\left\{\frac{\tilde{f_n}}{||\tilde{f_n}||_*}\;|\; \tilde{f_n}\in \tilde{D}\right\}$$ then $D$ is countable. Fixed $\varepsilon> 0$ and $f\in U$, since $f\in X^*$ exists $\tilde{f_n}\in\tilde{D}$ such that $$||f-\tilde{f_n}||_*<\varepsilon.$$ We cosider now $$f_n:=\frac{\tilde{f_n}}{||\tilde{f_n}||_*}$$ then $f_n\in D$

I must prove that $$||f-f_n||_*<\varepsilon$$

$$||f-f_n||=\frac{1}{||f||}\left\lVert f-\tilde{f_n}+(||\tilde{f_n}||-||f||)\frac{\tilde{f_n}}{||\tilde{f_n}||} \right\rVert\le \frac{1}{||f||}\left[\lVert f-\tilde{f_n}\rVert + \big|\lVert\tilde{f_n}\rVert-\lVert f \rVert\big|\right]< 2\varepsilon$$
I used the fact that $$\big|\lVert\tilde{f_n}\rVert-\lVert f \rVert\big|\le \lVert \tilde{f_n}-f \rVert$$

It's correct? We can assume that every $\tilde{f_n}\ne 0$?


Hint: $|x-y|<\epsilon$ implies $||x|-|y||<\epsilon$.

Yes, you can assume that $\tilde{f_n}\neq 0$. The zero function can safely be removed from any dense set.
